# What should I check from nginx & php-fpm / FastCGI sent in stderr: “Primary script unknown” while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx

As I know, when I meet "File not fount" error from Nginx & php-fpm server,

I have to check the each process's owner:group.

Look below.

[image]

the owner for php-fpm process is 'nginx'
and
the owner for nginx process is 'nginx'
and
the owner of the file www.sock is 'nginx' too.

But my website has 'file not found' error yet.
What should I check another?

-------- nginx conf -------

```
root         /home/gotoabc/pixel/www;
...
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    ...
```

------ /etc/php-fpm-7.2.d/www.conf ---------

```
user = nginx
group = hosting
...
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/www.sock
...
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = hosting
listen.mode = 0660
```

-------- /home/gotoabc/pixel/www ---------

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gotoabc hosting   5878 Dec 11 03:09 index.php
```

Comment: Please provide your nginx site config and your fpm pool config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging the famous - FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261922/debugging-the-famous-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown-while-re)

Comment: Unsure if that ^^ will help, but shouldn't hurt.