# How to enable access log for php-fpm in docker container?

Tags: php, docker, logging, fpm

Note: I am NOT talking about nginx' own access log. That one works fine. This questions is about enabling the php-fpm `access.log`.

---

Currently, I am trying to debug [the FastCGI sent in stderr: “Primary script unknown” while reading response header from upstream error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261922/debugging-the-famous-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-.primary-script-unknown-while-re/51385059)

One [proposed option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40535412/457268) is to set the access.log entry in the `php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

```
access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log
```

Now, I have a docker stack and my php-fpm container is build from the [php:7.3-fpm-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.3-fpm-alpine/images/sha256-d8dd6b21bf763b1bc2ff60b267fc84f16f1b231bbe1f5257c1cc3ca53c1ebe3b?context=explore) image.

While I have figured out that it stores its php config files at:

```
/usr/local/etc/php
```

and I also found the `www.conf` at:

```
/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

So in a local file I add the default content as provided by the image and add at the end:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log
```

and I copy that file during build into the docker container.

```
COPY ./.docker/php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Yet when I try to access my server, I don't see any log file being created on incoming requests.

What am I missing to activate the php-fpm access log? How can I figure out why I don't see any log?

Comment: Have you checked file permissions for the log path? Have you tried naming the file explicitly, create it through dockerfile with touch and modify the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to send the error and the access logs to the following address:

```
/proc/self/fd/2
```

So replace the "file" locations like so:

```
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
```

Then you should be able to inspect the fpm-logs with `docker logs [container-id]`