# HTTP ERROR 500 While try to connect to RDS in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm with a problem, always when I try to make a new account, login, or something else involving RDS, the page returns *HTTP ERROR 500*, I tried to make a script to only connect to the RDS using PDO, however I get error, it's clear that the problem is to connect in RDS in my EC2 instance, I really don't know what to do, I can make login in RDS using my EC2 instance in the console, it works, but using script it doesn't works, the page says *HTTP ERROR 500*
Please, I really need help, I want to use my RDS db with EC2, but it is not working and I don't know what to do

I already allowed my EC2 instance to connect to the RDS in the security group, but as I said, it only connects in command line, not in PHP script

```
[Thu Sep 03 02:15:59.100708 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 10451] [client 52.247.193.244:45920] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Thu Sep 03 12:10:11.913268 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 10477] [client 40.71.11.192:52180] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/kerbynet
[Thu Sep 03 12:52:08.589937 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11748] [client 200.22.90.64:15727] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/kerbynet
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Where can I see logs? Pls, I don' know

Comment: Look I edited the questions, you can see logs in /var/log/httpd

Comment: Is it because I only allowed my ec2 instance to access the RDS db? So, do I need to allow everywhere to access to the db? I'm not trying to access the site via EC2, but in my local computer, and the IP from the computer is different from EC2, so is it the problem?

Comment: It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261922/debugging-the-famous-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown-while-re) might be something similar.