# How to Configure Nginx to Execute PHP

Tags: php, nginx

This is config of `nginx.conf`

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

            include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index /index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard$fastcgi_script_name;

         } 

    }
```

But when I'm running on 127.0.0.1:9000 it doesn't work. On localhost it shows 403 Forbidden. As you can see, I deleted commented lines.

Comment: Access in /Users/*name*/PHPSITE/standard?

Comment: I gave access, chmod+x, but same thing, on localhost 403 Forbidden and on 127.0.0.1:9000 is nothing. :/

Comment: use telnet to check if you are able to connect?
telnet 127.0.0.1 9000

Comment: Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: make sure that you run PHP in www.conf using port not socket file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `$document_root` instead providing root path everywhere

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And check if your php-fpm process is running, for example if you are using systemctl run

```
systemctl status php-fpm
systemctl start php-fpm
```

also check if you are using same fast_cgi path, it should match in www.conf of php-fpm file ( could be here /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf)

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

and your site config nginx.conf file

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

after updating files restart your Nginx/php-fpm services.

and than visit http://localhost (as you set server_name above) in your browser , not 127.0.0.1:9000.